# Git - how to update an old commit

Tags: git, version-control

This is my graph:

```
Branch A    a-->b
                |
                v
Branch B        b-->c
```

I have branch `B` that came out of branch `A`, from commit `b`.
I did a commit on branch `B` called `c`.

Now let's say I update commit `b` of branch `A` with `git commit --amend` to `b'`

```
Branch A    a-->b'
                |
                v
Branch B        b-->c
```

How do I update comit `b` on branch `B` to be the exact `b'` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the grap is

```
a--b (A)
    \
     c (B)
```

After amend, you would have a new `b'` (marking `b` as `tmp`):

```
a--b' (A)
 \
  b--c (B)
(tmp)
```

You would need to rebase B onto A:

```
git rebase --onto A tmp B

a--b' (A)
    \
     c' (B)
```

As [divyum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426684/divyum) comments, you can also merge, but that would add to A, and duplicate `b` commit between, resulting in possible conflicts:

```
a--b'--M (A)
 \    /
  b--c (B)
```

I prefer cherry-picking or rebasing.

Comment: won't merge A into B or cherry-pick commits from A to B help?

Comment: @divyum `rebase --onto` is cherry-picking every commit after `tmp` up to `B` HEAD and replay them onto `A`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309.

Comment: ohk, makes sense or rather merge A into B. @VonC

Comment: @divyum if you have only one commit on B, yes a merge is possible to.

Comment: I guess number of commits don't matter, you can merge it anyway.